# How to convert a React component to an image?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, image

I want to convert a React component (that may include other components as children) to an image. Basically, I want to create an image view of the particular HTML portion. How can I do it? Any library from either ReactJS or Javascript will work.

Comment: did it progress any further?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking @kharel

Comment: @kharel check out my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it using `node-html-to-image` module in backend which uses `puppeteer`. Basically, puppeteer generates a virtual browser where the component is loaded and an image is captured.

You need to pass your html code to backend and generate the image.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-html-to-image

Answer (score 0):

You can use this package https://github.com/hcorta/react-to-image It is entirely on the frontend. It works by generating an image from a DOM node using HTML5 canvas and SVG.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the following library to convert your React component to image.
"html2canvas"

npm install html2canvas